# Using Android speech recognition API

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Is there any way I can make an app using jelly bean's offline speech recognition api & choose the sensitivity?

Actually I want to build an app, which tests user's English speaking & score.

If anyone can provide link to an app that currently does the same thing, that will be helpful too, because on that case I wouldn't need build an app to help myself

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12839663/using-android-jellybeans-stand-alone-speech-recognizer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an offline speech recognition on android, use Pocketsphinx:

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2011/05/building-pocketsphinx-on-android/

Comment: thanks for your resource. But I will use the online API instead.